# Customized UIImagePickerController issue when loaded a second time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I have made a UIImagePickerController with a custom overlay view in order to enhance the interface and it's working great the first time I load it, it's perfect.
The problem is that if I dismiss it and then shows it again I have a strange bug. the camera view and the overlay appear behind the NavBar and the TabBar of the previous view controller.

I have try different ways of implementing this but I can't get this bug solved.

Here is how I call my UIImagePickerController. It's inspired by [this sample code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rvMZ.jpg).

```
[self.cameraOverlayViewController setupImagePicker:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
[self presentModalViewController:self.cameraOverlayViewController.imagePickerController animated:YES];
```

Once my picture taken, I dismiss the UIImagePickerController:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Definitly nothing special in the way of implementing it.

And here 2 screenshots:

[image: At first launch]

And now taken at second launch:
[At second launch http://puic.dev.madebykawet.com/IMG_0929.PNG](http://puic.dev.madebykawet.com/IMG_0929.PNG)

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: can you post the code how you are loading the image picker controller and a screenshot to explain the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help Peko but it was not that.

After hours trying stuff, I found out that I needed to launch the UIImagePickerController from the root controller.
This is maybe because I'm using TTNavigator from the Three20 library.

So in my case to have this working:

```
[[TTNavigator navigator].rootViewController presentModalViewController:self.cameraOverlayViewController.imagePickerController animated:YES];
```

instead of:

```
[self presentModalViewController:self.cameraOverlayViewController.imagePickerController animated:YES];
```

same thing for dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:

```
[[TTNavigator navigator].rootViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something like that?

```
//hide all controls
picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
picker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
picker.toolbarHidden = YES;
```